# Get a value from a different form in javascript and store in a php session

Tags: javascript, php

Am trying to get a value from a different form to store in a session. When the user clicks on Calculate on form one it opens form two.In form two the user enters a value in a  textfield. Now incase the user presses the calculate button again I would want the page to store the values in form two in a session so that when form two re appears the value is stored.

is there a way to use javascript to store it in a php session

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['calculate']))
{
   $_SESSION['ss'] = '<script>doument.form[frm2].ss.value</script>'; 

}
?>
<form action="" method="post" name="frm1" id = "frm1" enctype="multipart/form-data" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
<input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="calculate" id="calculate">
<form>
<?php 
 if(isset($_POST['calculate'])){        
?>          ?>
<form action="go.php" method="post" name="frm2" id = "frm1" enctype="multipart/form-data" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
<input type="text" name="ss" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
<form>
<?php 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `jQuery` can try this way .

first define a hidden field in form 1

```
<form action="" method="post" name="frm1" id = "frm1" enctype="multipart/form-data" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
<input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_ss" name="hidden_ss" value=""/>
<input type="submit" name="calculate" id="calculate">
</form>
```

Then in jQuery when you change the `frm2 -> ss` value add the value to hidden field

```
$("input[name='ss']").change(function(){

    $("#hidden_ss").val($(this).val());
});
```

then wen you create calculate button

```
<?php
   $ss = trim($_POST['hidden_ss']);
?>
<form action="" method="post" name="frm1" id = "frm1" enctype="multipart/form-data" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
<input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_ss" name="hidden_ss" value=""/>
<input type="submit" name="calculate" id="calculate">
</form>

<?php 
 if(isset($_POST['calculate'])){        
?>          ?>
<form action="go.php" method="post" name="frm2" id = "frm1" enctype="multipart/form-data" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
<input type="text" name="ss" value="<?php echo $ss; ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
<?php 
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you don't need JavaScript for this.
Just something like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="frm1" id = "frm1" enctype="multipart/form-data" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
    <input type="text" name="id" value="<?=htmlentities($_SESSION['id'])?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="calculate" id="calculate">
</form>

<?php 
 if(isset($_POST['calculate']))
 {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];
    ?>
     <form action="go.php" method="post" name="frm2" id = "frm1" enctype="multipart/form-data" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
         <input type="text" name="ss" value="<?=htmlentities($_SESSION['id'])?>" />
         <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
     </form>
<?php 
 }
?>
```

Comment: The session should get value from frm2 ss